# Linq orderby for complex expression in select

Tags: c#, linq

guys!
I've got the code like following:

```
String input_string = "Good bye world!";
from c in input_string.Split(new char[]{' '})                   
    select int.Parse(c);
```

and I would like to order resulting query by int.Parse(c) like

```
String input_string = "Good bye world!";
from c in input_string.Split(new char[]{' '})
    orderby int.Parse(c)                    
    select int.Parse(c);
```

but without calculating int.Parse(c); again in orderby statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd go for @dtb's solution using `let`, but parsing `"Good"` (and the other string parts) to int does not make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `let`:

```
var input = "3 2 1";

var query = from c in input.Split(' ')
            let x = int.Parse(c)
            orderby x
            select x;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input_string = "111 222 333";
var result = input_string.Split(null)
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .OrderBy(arg => arg)
    .ToList();
```